# Get a specific word of of the sentence

Tags: jquery

H
ow can i get 123 out of ::123:: in a sentence then store it in a variable.

for example :

```
hi i am john ::123::.
```

It will look for :::: tags and get 123 from the it and strip off other words in the sentence.
The results would be `123`

I am not sure but is this able to work?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var store = $('.div').find(/::([^:]+)::/g);
    alert(store);
});
```

How can i do this using jquery?

Comment: `var store = $('.div').text().match(/::([^:]+)::/g);`

Comment: @Rob W, this could be answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the textual contents using [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/), then use [`String.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to use the RegEx:

```
var store = $('.div').text().match(/::([^:]+)::/g);
```